# CSS move new fields to top right hand corner

Tags: html, css

I have a containing div which creates the 'user' section of the page, the user details such as name, age etc. sit in the top left hand corner of this page. I have a new requirement where two 'status' type fields will need to be placed in the top right hand corner where there is sufficient space available.

I think that the 3 mentioned fields are filling all this space so the new fields are on the right, but sitting beneath.

I have put together a JSFiddle showing my problem, float right does not seem to be working for me, and I cant work out where im going wrong. I am not the best at CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/bxY9X/

```
<div class="user">
    <p><strong>Name:</strong> Bob </p>
    <p><strong>Age: </strong> 36 </p>
    <p><strong>Height: </strong> 5ft 11 </p>
    <br />

<div class="user2">
    <p><strong>Application Status:</strong>Awaiting Payment</p>
    <p><strong>Insurance Status:</strong>Valid</p>    

    </div>  
    </div>

.user2
{
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.user {
background-color: #E3E3E3;
height: 20%;
margin: 20px 0;
text-align: left;
width: 94.5%;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px 40px 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can try this also this is more preferred:
```

[Here is JSfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/bxY9X/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/bxY9X/5/)

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="user">
    <div class="user1">
    <p><strong>Name:</strong> Bob </p>
    <p><strong>Age: </strong> 36 </p>
    <p><strong>Height: </strong> 5ft 11 </p>
    <br />
    </div>
<div class="user2">
    <p><strong>Application Status:</strong>Awaiting Payment</p>
    <p><strong>Insurance Status:</strong>Valid</p>    

    </div>  
    </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
 .user2
{
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: right;
float:right;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
     display:inline-block;
}
.user1
{
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    height: 20%;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.user {
background-color: #E3E3E3;
height: 20%;
margin: 20px 0;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
border-radius: 5px 40px 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust both your HTML and CSS per the below.

Crucially the two floated areas need to be encapsulated within separate `div` elements, with `overflow:hidden;` then set on the parent (`.user`)

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxY9X/2/)

HTML

```
<div class='user'>
    <div>
        <p><strong>Name:</strong> Bob</p>
        <p><strong>Age: </strong> 36</p>
        <p><strong>Height: </strong> 5ft 11</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><strong>Application Status:</strong>Awaiting Payment</p>
        <p><strong>Insurance Status:</strong>Valid</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.user {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    height: 20%;
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 94.5%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px 40px 5px 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.user div:first-child{
    float:left;
}
.user div:last-child{
    float:right;
}
```